# Svelte notification on updated binding

Tags: svelte, svelte-3

Is there any way to find which binding is updated in Svelte?
I have a list of  elements bound to the array of values and would like to visually mark the updated values when the underlying array changes.

Comment: Please provide an example of what you talking and what you need to achieve.

Comment: I would like to apply a class to a node when a bound variable changes. Basically sth like INotifyPropertyChanged interface in WPF world.

Answer (score 1):

You can define your class like this:

```
<style>
:global(.myclass){
  background-color:pink;
}
</style>
```

Then svelte won’t add random string in your classnames (see my comment in other answer) and you can add the class to a node in your function.
Here is the REPL: https://svelte.dev/repl/01b8ed826cb64c119567060a64014925?version=3.28.0

Comment: Thanks, this helped, see my updated REPL for a nicely animated notification.

Answer (score 0):

This is the nearly working solution, however I would prefer to assign a class, not a style, but this does not seem to work: the class is assigned using

```
node.className="..."
```

But it has no effect somehow.

https://svelte.dev/repl/d0b90cca3c904a7c8f9555de1a1e6cf5?version=3.28.0

Comment: Svelte adds a random string to each class in order to isolate styling from other components or dom elements. You can see added string if you use developer tools or in REPL open the tab called CSS output. Therefore if you try to add a `className` for example `myclass` it won’t be enough, because svelte has changed your style `.myclass.svelte-vz17d{...}`